# Having more than 1 facebook comment box in a webpage

Tags: facebook, comments

Is it possible to have more than 1 facebook comment box in a single webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to specify a different url for the comments to be associated with

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=link1.com&permalink=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe> 

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=link2.com&permalink=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:130px; height:16px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```